# bash variable declaration with % operator

Tags: bash

I'm going through a bash script and I can't understand this statement not able to search for it:

```
IPV=${IPTABLES%tables}
```

what does this statement means?

Comment: Documented [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), or `info bash` and search for "Shell Parameter Expansion".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of parameter substitution (and not related to the math operator). There are many more examples here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html

> ${var%Pattern} Remove from $var the shortest part of $Pattern that matches the back end of $var.
>
> ${var%%Pattern} Remove from $var the longest part of $Pattern that matches the back end of $var.

For example:

```
$ export IPTABLES=footables
$ echo ${IPTABLES%tables}
foo
```

Answer (score 1):

A variable like you show `${IPTABLES%table}` is called a parameter, and the `%` is a parameter modifier.

There are 4 basic parameter modifers in this "set"

```
  ${var#str*x}   #   removes str and the shortest match to x from left side of variable's value 
  ${var##str*x}  # removes longest match of str and everything to the farthest x


  ${var%str}   # removes str from the right side of the variable's value
  ${var%x*str} # removes shortest match of x*str from the right side 
  ${var%%x*str}  # removes longest match of x*str from right side
```

So `${var#X}` and `${var##X}` count for 2, and `${var%X}`, `${var%%X}` make another two.

There are others, depending on versions and bash, vs ksh, vs zsh

So play with

```
 var=abcxstrxyz
 echo ${var%#str}
 echo ${var%str*}
 echo ${var%%str}
 echo ${var%%str*}
```

Etc to get a sense of what this can do.

IHTH